# What is the difference between Model::ConstInterp and Model::Eval?

Tags: z3

I had been using ConstInterp to get the values of constant literals in an expr.

```
model.ConstInterp(lit)
```

however i got a strange error

```
... <body of some loop>
let x = model.ConstInterp(lit)
if solver.Check() == Status.SATISFIABLE
then model.ConstInterp(lit)
```

the *second* call to ConstInterp produces an error

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Z3.Z3Exception: invalid argument
   at Microsoft.Z3.Native.Z3_model_get_const_interp(IntPtr a0,IntPtr a1,IntPtr a2)
   at Microsoft.Z3.Model.ConstInterp(FuncDecl f)
   at Microsoft.Z3.Model.ConstInterp(Expr a)
```

However the same code with Eval instead of ConstInterp its fine. Was I using ConstInterp incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call to model.ConstInterp() uses a model that was constructed during a previous call to Check(), so it may contain different constant interpretations, but this is only a secondary issue here.

It is not required that all constants have an interpretation in every model, e.g., when the assignment of a constant is not required to satisfy all constraints, it may be left unassigned (and therefore missing in the model). For instance, consider the following program:

```
Solver s = ctx.MkSolver();
s.Add(ctx.MkOr(
    ctx.MkEq(x, ctx.MkTrue()),
    ctx.MkEq(x, ctx.MkFalse()))); // Assert x = false OR x = true
s.Add(ctx.MkEq(y, ctx.MkTrue())); // Assert y = false
s.Check(); // Returns Status.SATISFIABLE
```

This program does not constrain `x`, but it does constrain `y`. Consequently, the model will not contain a value for `x` and `s.Model.ConstInterp(x)` will throw an assertion. A call to `s.Model.Eval(x)` will not throw an assertion, but it will also not evaluate `x`; in this instance we get `s.Model.Eval(x) == x`. This behavior can be changed by setting the second parameter of `Eval()` to true, thereby enabling model completion, i.e.,

```
s.Model.Eval(x, true)
```

will return `false`.

As an alternative, the array `s.Model.ConstDecls` contains all function declarations of constants which have an interpretation in the model. Constants which are not in this set do not have an interpretation and can be assumed to be 'don't-cares', i.e., any value may be assigned to them.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that if a variable can be left unassigned, it will be? I have a disjunction of conjunctions, and I want to be able to tell which conjunctions were "used". This is easy if I add a free variable T_i to every conjunction, because it will be set to true if the conjunction otherwise holds. Once a conjunction is sat, are all other T variables going to unassigned? I tried adding an additional set of conjunctions to the disjunction that said `T_n -> Conj_n` so that they would forcibly be set false for conjunctions that were unsat, but this made model extraction extremely slow.

Comment: Oops, found a concrete example after posting that: no. :) But I found a smarter encoding in "Efficient CNF Encoding for Selecting 1 from N Objects" that helped keep things fast.